# Can't add or update a list

Tags: flutter, dart

So I'm trying to make a list that contains some widgets and then add a new widget to it when I press a button, but it doesn't seem to be working

This is the code:

```
class MessagesProvider extends ChangeNotifier{


 List<dynamic> mesgs = [
    new chatBubbleSend(),
    new chatBubbleReceiver(),
    new chatBubbleReceiver()
  ];
  bool loading = true;

  addMesg(){
    mesgs.add(chatBubbleSend());
    print(mesgs.length);
    print(mesgs);
    notifyListeners();
  }
  printMesg(){
    print(mesgs.length);
    print(mesgs);
  }
  removeMesg(){
    mesgs.removeLast();
    print(mesgs.length);
    print(mesgs);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

and this is what i get when i press the add, remove or print buttons
[add](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yip0J.png),[remove](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7udV.png),[print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P27jR.png)

and this is the list builder code

```
ChangeNotifierProvider<MessagesProvider>(
                create: (context) => MessagesProvider(),
                child: ChatMessages()
                  ),
class ChatMessages extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final mesgs = Provider.of<MessagesProvider>(context, listen: false).mesgs;
    return ListView.builder(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemCount: mesgs.length,
      itemBuilder: (context,index)=> mesgs[index],
    );
  }
}
```

I have looking for a solution for over 8 hours now, and still, I couldn't fix it.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. please, copy and paste the code into your question. if you do it so, the community will be able to reproduce it and will help you easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I jumped the gun with my first answer sorry.
When trying to recreate I ran into the same frustrating issue - focusing on the the provider being the problem until I realised it's actually the rendering of the updated list that's the issue.

You need to use a list builder to render the updating list in a change notifier consumer in a stateful widget

Full working example below:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';


class WidgetListProvider with ChangeNotifier {

  List<Widget> widgets = [];

  int listLength = 0;

  void addWidget(){
    Widget _widget = Text('Hello');
    widgets.add(_widget);
    listLength = widgets.length;
    print('Added a widget');
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void removeWidget(){
    if (widgets.length > 0) {
      widgets.removeLast();
      listLength = widgets.length;
      print('Removed a widget');
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }

}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  HomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  Widget _appBar (BuildContext context) {
    return AppBar(
      title: Text('My App'),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: _appBar(context),
      // You need to define widgets that update when a provider changes
      // as children of a consumer of that provider
      body: Consumer<WidgetListProvider>(builder: (context, widgetProvider, child){
        return Container(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              RaisedButton(
                child: Text('Add widget'),
                onPressed: () {
                  widgetProvider.addWidget();
                },
              ),
              RaisedButton(
                child: Text('Remove Widget'),
                onPressed: () {
                  widgetProvider.removeWidget();
                },
              ),
              Row(
                children: [
                  Text('Number of Widgets: '),
                  Text(widgetProvider.listLength.toString()),
                ],
              ),
              Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.6,
                child: ListView.builder(itemCount: widgetProvider.widgets.length, itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
                  return widgetProvider.widgets[index];
                })
              )
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
      ),
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(
      ChangeNotifierProvider(
        create: (context) => WidgetListProvider(),
        child: MyApp(),
      )
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'My App',
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: hi, thanks for answering, I tried this  already and it doesn't seems to work, and the main problem its not the updating it  self but it is that the List variable is not adding or removing items inside it, so for example when I call the function addMesg it prints in the console that it did add the item and the List have 4 items now, but when I try to print the items in the list again nothing is changed and there is still 3 items left,

Comment: This was actually harder to answer than I first thought - but the solution above now works